# Why can't I connect to 127.0.0.1 HortonWorks Dashboard?

Tags: hadoop, networking, virtualbox, hortonworks-sandbox

I have installed Virtual Box (Version 5.2.0 r118431 (Qt5.6.2)) on Windows 10 and i imported appliance HDP_2.4_virtualbox_v3 (downloaded from [here](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B-jzSsn2sslITFhHNUU2aF9aWW8&export=download)).

I followed the tutorial from [here](https://hortonworks.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/InstallingHortonworksSandboxonWindowsusingVB.pdf) step by step.

The virtual machine is running on the computer from where I am trying to access the Dashboard. I have set up the Host Only Adapter Option on the sandbox so the computer and the virtual machine can communicate

After the CentOs finished booting I am prompt to enter to the ip 127.0.0.1:8888, which is a different address from the tutorial,

and there is no server listening to that address because i get

"127.0.0.1 refused to connect." in the browser.

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcUHN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the `ipconfig` command in your command prompt and identyfy your virtual box's ip under `Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network`.

Take that ip address and go to your Virtual Box.

Select your appliance and go to `Settings->Network->Adapter 1->Port Forwarding.`

Replace the Host IP 127.0.0.1 for the port you need 8080, 8888 and so on with the ip of your virtual box that should be sth like **192.168.x.x**.

Now start your sandbox, login on it and try to connect in your browser to the new ip set **192.168.x.x:8888**.

Use appliance `HDP_2.4_virtualbox` because in the most recent some linux commands like netstat are considered deprecated and no longer function, which willmake your life harder when trying to debug or identify a networking problem.

If you still encounter issues eith it, reinstall your operating system, reinstall your virtual box and reimport the sandbox, make the changes needed in the Port Forwarding settings and it should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

try to connect using 127.0.0.1 to connect make sure the VM is running make sure there are no errors if there are debug them and at the last straw uninstall the Vm and retry (make sure to make a backup if there are any files)

you can also try to check all the local host ips on your network and try to connect to them

Comment: Where am I supposed to see if there are any errors? The VM is surely running and it is the third time i'm reinstalling it and trying other sandbox versions

Comment: if its running normally just try to connect to multiple diffrent local hyost ips

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set NAT in your VirtualBox network settings:

[image]